# Issues with embedding PDF in pptx using docx4j

Tags: java, pdf, powerpoint, docx4j

I have to attach a pdf file in a pptx slide during runtime.

Tried the following:

Attached a pdf file in the pptx slide (Insert -> Object -> Adobe Acrobat Document). 
Accessed the oleobject using the following code :

```
OleObjectBinaryPart oleObjectBinaryPart = new OleObjectBinaryPart(new PartName("/ppt/embeddings/oleObject1.bin"));
```

Updating the oleObjectBinaryPart using the following code:

```
oleObjectBinaryPart.setBinaryData(reportBlob.getBinaryStream());
```

Updating the pptx with the new oleobject:

```
pptMlPackage.getParts().getParts().put(new PartName("/ppt/embeddings/oleObject1.bin"), oleObjectBinaryPart);
pptMlPackage.save(new File("C:/test_report/pptx_out.pptx"));
```

After executing this code the pptx_out.pptx file got generated without any errors.  But while trying to open the embedded pdf in powerpoint 2010 I'm getting following error:

> The server application, source file, or item can't be found, or returned an unknown error. You may need to reinstall the sever application.

Is it a problem with the oleobject when updating?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just attach the PDF as a binary blob; it has to be in the correct OLE format.

See further [this discussion](http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/how-to-create-an-oleobject-bin-for-video-or-pdf-t72.html).